# DBLookup parameter values as registry entries doesn't work

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

WSO2 EI 6.3.0

DBLookup parameter values as registry entries are evaluate like literal. I read https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/DBLookup+Mediator but is not working for me.

Me dblookup configuration

```
<dblookup description="Checking historical">
    <connection>
        <pool>
            <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
            <url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databasename=test</url>
            <user>conf:/custom/config.xml/database/user</user>
            <password>somepass</password>
        </pool>
    </connection>
    <statement>
        <sql><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM someTable]]></sql>
    </statement>
</dblookup>
```

and the exception

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Login failed for user 'conf:/custom/config.xml/database/user'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username which you are using will not work for the reason .

```
 <user>conf:/custom/config.xml/database/user</user>
```

The user field tries to read the value saved in a file, here you are reading from `config.xml` however and later you are providing relative path in the .xml ,hence it will not work.

I would suggest that you save the username in a registry file and then access the user name, that should work.